# LInQ - Grouping a list on an id

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have list `List<PersonDTO>`.
`PersonDTO` is defined as follows:

```
PersonDTO
{
    public int PersonId;
    public int Name;
    public int OrderId;
    public string OrderName;
    public string OrderType;
}
```

There is a `Person` class which contains a list of Orders as mentioned below

```
Person
{
    public int PersonId;
    public int Name;
    List<Orders> orders;
}

public Order
{
    public int OrderId;
    public string OrderName;
    public string OrderType;
}
```

I want to group the list of `PersonDTO` by `PersonId` and generate a list of `Person` objects such that all the orders of that person are in the `List<Orders>`.

How can I achieve this using LINQ.

Much Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to do so far, and what problems are you having with those attempts?

Comment: `How can I achieve this using LINQ` By starting writing some code.

Comment: @Servy

First I tried with the normal approach of finding an id in the personlist, if the id exists add the order from new PrsonDTO object to the existing person otherwise add a new Person object to the list. This approach ofcourse worked.
I wanted to do this with Linq, so this is what I was trying
`var query = from p in personDTOList
            group new Person
     {
  PersonId = p.PersonId,
  Name = p.Name,
            } by p.PersonId into g
            select new Order
     {
      // wanted to populate the list here from g
     }` I was not able to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: @L.B..This is the first time I am using LINQ and I do intent to learn it properly and practice through code. May be a few days from now, questions like these would sound to easy to me like how it appeared to you I guess. :)

Comment: @Gunjan You should include that in your question, not in a comment to your question, and it should have been there from the start.

Comment: @Servy - Will take care of doing that going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what you want:

```
var people = personDTOs.GroupBy(i => i.PersonId).Select(
    // Each PersonId group projects a single Person object.
    i => new Person() {
        PersonId = i.Key,
        // Assuming that all names in this group are the same.
        Name = i.First().Name,
        // The elements in the group are used to project Order objects.
        orders = i.Select(o => new Order() {
            OrderId = o.OrderId,
            OrderName = o.OrderName,
            OrderType = o.OrderType
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Spoon-feeding makes me sad.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed. This and the above response are same so either one solves my issue :). Thanks again for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
List<PersonDTO> list = new List<PersonDTO>();
List<Person> personList = list.GroupBy(r => r.PersonId)
    .Select(grp => new Person()
    {
        PersonId = grp.Key,
        Name = grp.First().Name,
        orders = grp.Select(r => new Order()
        {
            OrderId = r.OrderId,
            OrderName = r.OrderName,
            OrderType = r.OrderType
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

But remember, if your `Person` and `Order` class is generated through Entity framework or LINQ To SQL you can't use them in projection.